# Mathematical method of classical Mechanics Arnold

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, education, specific-reference, complex-systems

I wanted to know that is there any textbook or PDF file containg suloutin of the book Mathematical methods of classical mechanics by Arnolʹd

Some of the questions are really hard.

Comment: What do you find with a search action?

Comment: Nothing! do you have a pdf file on any recommendation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic.